# TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this code to make my nav sticky after `#header1` div. It works fine for me but the issue is my console shows an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Please provide me some solutions for it. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var navHeight = $(".header1").height();
    ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) ? $('.afterLgnRow').addClass('goToTop') : $('.afterLgnRow').removeClass('goToTop');
  });
});

$('.afterLgnRow').affix({
  offset: { 
    top: $('#header1').offset().top 
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post your html, too.  Did you maybe mean `$(".header1")` instead of `$('#header1')`? Or vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because `offset()` is returning nothing as you're attempting to work with the `#header1` element before the DOM is ready. To fix this move the code inside the document.ready handler.

Also note that `bind()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead, and you can simplify the `addClass()`/`removeClass()` logic by using `toggleClass()` with a boolean.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var navHeight = $(".header1").height();     
    $('.afterLgnRow').toggleClass('goToTop', $(window).scrollTop() > navHeight);
  });

  $('.afterLgnRow').affix({
    offset: { 
      top: $('#header1').offset().top 
    }
  });
});
```

I also note that you're accessing both `#header1` and `.header1` - ensure these selectors are correct.